# I keep receiving an empty message error when trying to post a webhook

Tags: discord, discord.js

This is my first time using Discord embeds, let alone, making a webhook. Having a little bit of trouble trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Hopefully someone can help!

When I try to send an embed with a message with this code:

```
{
  "username": "Official Discord Servers",
  "avatar_url": "https://imgur.com/a/Cl3zspb",
  "embeds": [{
    "description": "Here is a list of official Discord servers maintained by our State. Note that most of these servers may restrict full access to those who are members of their respective departments:",
    "color": 16007990,
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "State of Atoll",
        "value": "[Discord Server](https://discord.gg/5KKgb2z)"
      },
      {
        "name": "Atoll Law Enforcement Training Academy",
        "value": "[Discord Server](https://discord.gg/GJnbavz)"
      },
      {
        "name": "Atoll Department of Homeland Security",
        "value": "[Discord Server](https://discord.gg/acnPFa7)"
      },
      {
        "name": "Palm County Sheriff's Office",
        "value": "[Discord Server](https://discord.gg/uYFANDs)"
      },
      {
        "name": "Atoll State Police",
        "value": "[Discord Server](https://discord.gg/WNHKtra)"
      },
      {
        "name": "Atoll Department of Corrections",
        "value": "[Discord Server](https://discord.gg/VbFew9s)"
      },
      {
        "name": "Atoll National Guard",
        "value": "[Discord Server](https://discord.gg/6zE9HyW)"
  }]
}
```

I get this error:

> {
>       "code": 50006,
>       "message": "Cannot send an empty message"
>   }

Comment: Same issue even if I specify content field.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code?

Comment: @IvMisticos try providing your code sample via pastebin

Comment: I've provided solutions since it's not me having the issue anymore.

Answer (score 6):

You need to send "content" as a key value pair containing the content of the message being sent.

```
"content": "Just testing webhooks"
```

Answer (score 5):

It **requires** header `Content-Type` with value `application/json`. Also try setting `content` field.

Your issue is invalid JSON, so try using [JSON validator](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: If you just started having this problem, this is the correct answer!  Adding a Content-Type header to my Curl request fixed my problem.

-H "Content-Type:application/json"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The JSON referred in the question cannot be parsed, it is not properly formed, it is missing closing brackets. Please find last set of `}]` brackets in my answer below, try this,

```
{
  "username": "Official Discord Servers",
  "avatar_url": "https://imgur.com/a/Cl3zspb",
  "embeds": [{
    "description": "Here is a list of official Discord servers maintained by our State. Note that most of these servers may restrict full access to those who are members of their respective departments:",
    "color": 16007990,
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "State of Atoll",
        "value": "[Discord Server](https://discord.gg/5KKgb2z)"
      },
      {
        "name": "Atoll Law Enforcement Training Academy",
        "value": "[Discord Server](https://discord.gg/GJnbavz)"
      },
      {
        "name": "Atoll Department of Homeland Security",
        "value": "[Discord Server](https://discord.gg/acnPFa7)"
      },
      {
        "name": "Palm County Sheriff's Office",
        "value": "[Discord Server](https://discord.gg/uYFANDs)"
      },
      {
        "name": "Atoll State Police",
        "value": "[Discord Server](https://discord.gg/WNHKtra)"
      },
      {
        "name": "Atoll Department of Corrections",
        "value": "[Discord Server](https://discord.gg/VbFew9s)"
      },
      {
        "name": "Atoll National Guard",
        "value": "[Discord Server](https://discord.gg/6zE9HyW)"
      }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thinker. Can you please clarify, what exactly you've changed? Because its' hard to compare, you know.

Comment: Hello Misticos, please find last }] brackets in my answer, the JSON referred in the question cannot be parsed, it was missing closing brackets.

Comment: I know but you should IMO specify that in the answer.

Comment: Hello Misticos, thanks for your suggestion i have now update my answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was sending a plain text directly instead of JSON in the request. Then when I changed the message to the below it worked.

```
{content: "This is the message"}
```

If you are sending embeds, you can still keep the content set to null.